# Looking for a reverse dependency algorithm

Tags: algorithm

I have a list of dependencies, for example a BLT depends on having bacon, lettuce and tomato, while today's lunch depends on having a BLT and tomato soup.  I want to reverse the relationship, i.e. for all ingredients, list everything that depends on them.  Thus, bacon is required for both a BLT and today's lunch.  I know that package managers can do this, but I need the underlying algorithm.  Thanks.

Comment: How are you representing your dependency graph?

Comment: Store your dependency graph in an adjacency matrix instead of an adjacency list and just look up the edges in the different direction (swap the row/column in your lookup).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is breadth first search. Create a graph where A connects to B if B depends on A. Then, start a BFS from any node (call it A) you want to look up  what depends on it until termination(all reachable nodes have been traversed) and each node encountered during BFS depends on A.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search

Comment: This seems to answer the question "How do I know what X's dependencies are?", but not "How do I know what depends on X?"

Comment: Edited answer. Same idea but just reverse graph edge directions.